# win-ios-install.exe crashes instantly in the trigger.io build process

Tags: trigger.io

I've got a problem with the win-ios-install.exe used to install the trigger.io build on to the iOS device from Windows (which would be really useful).  During the build or if run straight from command prompt it goes down instantly with:-

"win-ios-install.exe has stopped working"

```
Faulting application name: win-ios-install.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4fbe652b
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d45fa
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0004373d
Faulting process ID: 0x1fd4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf1368945236b1
Faulting application path: C:\projects\wbprj\trigger\.lib\win-ios-install.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: d206997e-7f5b-11e3-bea7-a4badbfc4d4a
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Sometimes it will also popup a dialog box with a red cross and no title/message, just the OK button.

All other build steps are successful, and it happens with or without the device plugged in (tried ios6 and ios7 ipads).

I've tried to see if it's dependencies, but Dependency Walker just reports that it couldn't read the imports table and shows nothing.

I've tried compatability modes from xp/vista/win7, still same.  Checked permissions in the folder, all OK.  Stopped all other possible interfering services, including itunes helper, ensured UAC off, stopped windows defender, all still same crash.

A bit stumped now, so any help much appeciated.  Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013, latest iTunes also installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.

This happen under Windows 8.

I had to go back to Windows 7 to have everything work good. (i was about to leave Windows 8 so it's not a problem for me).

But it could be a reason for me to leave trigger.io because my next PC will be Windows 8.